# How to make click handler handle when ANY "a" tag is clicked, regardless of what it's wrapped around?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have this in my HTML page:

```
<a href="/foo">bar</a>

<a href="/">
    <div></div> 
</a>
```

And I want to write a handler that handles when ANY "a" tag is clicked (with jQuery):

```
$(document).click((e) => {
  const element = e.target;
  if (element && element.nodeName === 'A') {
    // Do something
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

The above code only works for the top "a" tag, but not the bottom one. For the top "a" tag, `element.nodeName` equals `A`. For the bottom "a" tag, `element.nodeName` equals `DIV`.

How do I write a click handler that handles whenever ANY "a" tag is clicked, regardless of what it is wrapped around?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Capture **delegated events** in any parent element. Document will get all events if you don't call `preventDefault` before it arrives during the **bubbling** phase. Read about Event phases, it really pays off!

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function(event) {

    // You have clicked an anchor
    window.console.log ("You have clicked this anchor:", this," but you clicked maybe inside a div or a something inside the <a>", event.target);

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7ttm4y8k/4/

Note: As you are delegating the events to the document, this will work even for elements that were added after the handler's been set. This way you can setup your delegated anchor handler then maybe at a later time add anchors from an Ajax query without the need of setting handlers to every created anchor.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the answer and also your explanation on why this works!

I have a lot to read up on

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/82fpvwrL/

```
 $("a").click(function(){
        alert('WOO HOO! I was clicked.'); 
    });
```

Comment: use preventDefault(); to avoid the reload... unless it's what you want... `$(document).ready(function(){ $("a").click(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); alert('WOO HOO! I was clicked.'); }); });`

Answer (score 0):

Apply it to every anchor.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('a').map(tag => tag.onClick = yourHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
$(document).on("click","a", (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   const element = e.target;
   // Do something
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how I do it (w/o jQuery):

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    var targetElement = ev.target;
    while(targetElement !== null && targetElement.nodeName.toUpperCase() !== "A") {
        targetElement = targetElement.parentElement;
    }

    // Proceed only if an A element was found in the ev.target's ancestry
    if (targetElement !== null) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        // Your code here
    }
}
```

This will catch the event at the `body` tag and is oblivious to `a` tags being added/removed in the document. It will work as long as the `click` event's propagation was not stopped by any elements in the DOM tree from the element to the `body`.

Comment: Only problem here is that you might want to account for browsers that don't support addEventListener.  Check caniuse.com

Comment: "browsers that don't support addEventListener" aka Internet Explorer 8.